# Manipulate drawn vectors using AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, vector

What I want to do is draw a shape using the pen tool and then manipulate this shape using AS3 to distort the anchor points. How can I access the anchor points etc from within AS3? I can convert the drawn shape to a movie clip symbol, and access this from the Action Script, but how do I then manipulate the vector?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you can't do it like that. A shape drawn in the IDE will not be editable once you export the swf.

If you want to create an animated element, you can draw with ActionScript, using the [Graphics API](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/Graphics.html), but you need to create your shape programmatically, and redraw the image every time an anchor changes.

If you actually want users to be able to draw in real time, there is no quick and easy way to do this, either: You need to create your own pen tool and anchors, draw lines between them, make them draggable, implement undo, etc.

Here are some "first steps" tutorials on how to do something like that in [AS2](http://www.actionscript.org/resources/articles/10/1/Creating-a-Dynamic-Drawing-application-in-Flash/Page1.html) and [AS3](http://kirill-poletaev.blogspot.com/2010/11/create-drawing-application-using-as3.html).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sorry I need to make myself clear, I don't want to make an application capable of drawing. I would like to draw a vector shape in the Flash interface, or import a vector file, and then use AS3 to manipulate the path data , anchors etc.

Comment: You can't do that, as I've said.  You can export your vector data in a readable format, load and parse it at runtime, and then store and  manipulate coordinates.  But you still need to draw the shape via ActionScript, and refresh the full image every time something changes.

Comment: I have done something like this for PostScript (tedious, but practical: you can export EPS from Illustrator or any other vector graphics program), and some custom xml data formats.  It's a lot of work...

Answer (score 0):

You might try programatically drawing your shape, and then redraw it with new point information at an interval suitable for your animation, with either an ENTER_FRAME event or a timer.